# How to switch form base of flag in HTML (Angular JS)

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to use same form for two different **Views** and I have two different **roles**.
**1. Client
2. Manager**

In my Controller I have added a flag based on the user role that is logged in.

```
$scope.userFlag=$rootScope.globalSession.UserRole,
```

If I login as a **Manager** then the value of **$rootScope.globalSession.UserRole="Manager"**

& If I login as a **Client** then the value of **$rootScope.globalSession.UserRole="Client"**

Now in my form I have added a condition to switch it -> **ng-if="userFlag==Admin"**

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="UpdateAdminProfileForm" id="UpdateAdminProfileForm">
           <h2>Update Profile</h2>
                <hr>
            <fieldset name="client" id="client" ng-if="userFlag==Admin">

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username">Domain Name*</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theClient.OrganizationDomain"  disabled>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="update"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a><button id="update" name="update" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateClient()">Update</button></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
          <fieldset name="manager" id="manager" ng-show="userFlag==Manager">

              <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': submitted && UpdateAdminProfileForm.myemail.$error.required || UpdateAdminProfileForm.myemail.$error.pattern }">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="myemail">Email*</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="myemail" name="myemail" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theClient.Email" ng-pattern="regex.Email" ng-maxlength="20" required  autofocus >
                        <span ng-show="submitted && UpdateAdminProfileForm.myemail.$error.required" class="help-block">Email can not be empty</span>
                        <span ng-show="UpdateAdminProfileForm.myemail.$error.pattern && UpdateAdminProfileForm.myemail.$invalid " class="help-block">Please enter a valid email</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" ng-click="updateManager()">Save</button>
    </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

But its not working when I open the form, its empty and If I remove **ng-if="userFlag==Admin"** & **ng-if="userFlag==Manager"** from  tags then it display the fields for both field set.

**Image With FLAG**

[image: With Flag]

**Image After Removing FLAG**

[image]

Help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
ng-if="userFlag=='Admin'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
ng-if="userFlag=='Admin'" or  ng-show="userFlag=='Manager'"
```